# update trigger get the updated primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger ,but I need to get the updated record's primary key (like as inserting the data SELECT @Id= @@IDENTITY) thus, I can pass it to where condition. How can I do that?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CariBakiyeBorcAktar]
       ON  [dbo].[BakimKartiDegisenParcalar]
       AFTER   UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Id int 
    DECLARE @CariId int 
    DECLARE @SId int 
    DECLARE @MId int
    declare @Tutar decimal
    declare @Bakiye decimal
    declare @s decimal = 0


    DECLARE @ParcaId int 


    --how I can I get the last updateed record Identity like this??
    --and pass it to update query as a where condition
    SELECT @Id= @@IDENTITY




    set @SId=(select SId from CariBakiye where Id =@Id)

    select @CariId=tblk.CariId ,@MId=tblk.MId, @SId= tblk.SId,@Tutar=tblk.Tutar from (
    SELECT tbl.CariId , tbl.MId,tbl.SId,tbl.Tutar from (select cb.MId,SUM(bk.Tutar) as  Tutar,bk.SId,cb.Id  as CariId FROM [BakimKartiDegisenParcalar] bk
    join  CariBakiye cb on cb.SId=bk.SId
     where bk.SId  =cb.SId group by bk.SId,cb.MId,cb.Id ) as tbl 
    ) as tblk  where SId = @SId

    set @Bakiye = @s-@Tutar


    update CariBakiye set Borc=@Tutar,Bakiye=@Bakiye where Id=@CariId

    print @Id
        -- Insert statements for trigger here

    END
```

Comment: This trigger is very badly broken. Triggers are fired per statement not per row in SQL Server so there can be multiple rows updated. You need to rewrite it using set based statements that refer to `INSERTED` / `DELETED` tables not `@@IDENTITY`

Comment: ummmm,any suggestion to fix it ?

Comment: I  already gave you a suggestion. I have no intention of actually doing it for you though.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said, you have to understand that SQL Server triggers are per statement, not per row. So in context of your trigger you have two tables - [inserted and deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx), where you could find all information about data updated. If you really want to do per row processing, you could use cursor:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CariBakiyeBorcAktar] ON  [dbo].[BakimKartiDegisenParcalar]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Id int 
    DECLARE @CariId int 
    DECLARE @SId int 
    DECLARE @MId int
    declare @Tutar decimal
    declare @Bakiye decimal
    declare @s decimal = 0

    DECLARE @ParcaId int 


    declare tr_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
        select ID from inserted

    while 1 = 1
    begin
        fetch tr_cursor into @Id
        if @@fetch_status <> 0 break

        set @SId=(select SId from CariBakiye where Id =@Id)

        select @CariId=tblk.CariId ,@MId=tblk.MId, @SId= tblk.SId,@Tutar=tblk.Tutar from (
        SELECT tbl.CariId , tbl.MId,tbl.SId,tbl.Tutar from (select cb.MId,SUM(bk.Tutar) as  Tutar,bk.SId,cb.Id  as CariId FROM [BakimKartiDegisenParcalar] bk
        join  CariBakiye cb on cb.SId=bk.SId
         where bk.SId  =cb.SId group by bk.SId,cb.MId,cb.Id ) as tbl 
        ) as tblk  where SId = @SId

        set @Bakiye = @s-@Tutar


        update CariBakiye set Borc=@Tutar,Bakiye=@Bakiye where Id=@CariId

        print @Id
            -- Insert statements for trigger here
    end
    close tr_cursor
    deallocate tr_cursor
END
```

Comment: I have 2 table ,when update the first table's row,tring to fire a triger to update a row in second table  which is before inserted by me,it seems using curser redandancy,whats u suggestion,should I use inserted and deleted , but in this case I have already inserted row,how can I use inserted.I just trying to understand tiger logic,I am new on this topic.thank you again

Comment: do you want me to write trigger for you?